# How to retrieve my app's source codes

Tags: android, ios

I've run into an issue and not sure how to solve. I worked with a developer to create an IOS and Android app. It's a paid app and I decided after about 6 months to create the same app and offer for free with ads. This should go smoothly, but the developer says his computer crashed and he no longer has my source files. I have a version, but not "the" version cause I was working with him through Elance and reached the upload limit to send files. Can I retrieve the files from Apple or Google Play somehow? Any other ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds unlikely. I don't recall in either type of app uploading the source code as part of the publishing procedure. Certainly with Android you tend to run Proguard, which would be a but pointless if you also uploaded the source code.

Comment: I have no idea how it works. I paid the developer to handle all of this.

Comment: You're better off trying to recreate it than to decompile it. It's not that simple a thing to do, especially since you weren't the developer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you are going to have troubles either way.  From what I know of Google Play, you need to have the unique signature (private key) compiled in to the APK when you upload it.  Since there is no way you'll get that again, you won't be able to duplicate it.

On the other hand, you would have to compile a NEW version anyway, since it is not a paid version.  So, assuming you have access to the source code at all, none of the first paragraph really applies.

Having said all that, what you need is an app decompiler.  I wish you luck with that.  But that's never as simple as it seems.  I'm afraid you may have to start from scratch.  Although, having done it once, you shouldn't have such a hard time with it...

Comment: Thanks for the input. The developer says he has too many projects now. I guess lesson learned.

Comment: And that lesson is in two parts.  1)  Always back up your source code.  2)  Never lose the private key you used.  Sorry about the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is this:

**A.** Pray that your developer had neglected to [obfuscate](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) your app's code

**B.** Download the APK from Google Play and use [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) to convert it into a standard Java jar.

**C.** Download jd java decompiler from [here](http://jd.benow.ca/) to convert the binary .class files inside the jar into text

**D.** Use [ApkTool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to convert the binary encoded XML files within your APK into textual XMLs.

**E.** Get into the habit of using [source control](https://github.com/)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to decompile a iOS- or Androidapp.